# I'm a Malaysian, lost passport in Italy and want to continue my trip on an emergency travel doc

Tags: passports, italy, paperwork, emergencies, malaysian-citizens

I'm currently on a four-week trip with my parents. I have all flight, accommodation and transport booked up for our trip in Germany, Italy, Austria and Switzerland. We have just started our trip and I got pickpocketed and lost my passport.

Anyone know if it is possible to continue doing the trip with an emergency travel document?

According to the Malaysian government website the emergency travel document is not recognized in Germany, Italy and Switzerland. It's my parents first trip in Europe and they really need me with them.

Comment: Do you have a link for "not recognized in Germany, Italy and Switzerland"?  Emergency travel documents are generally recognized everywhere if all you need to do is leave the country.

Comment: http://www.kln.gov.my/web/usa_washington/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/emergency-certificate